# Linux kernel file config enabling

Tags: bluetooth, linux-kernel, wifi, ubuntu-12.04, zynq

I have a piece of hardware (microzed board) which runs on linux (xillinux 1.3) based on ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS. I wanted to connect a peripheral (TI wifi/Bluetooth module) to my board. In order for the device to be detected and work I believe the device should be enabled. In my kernel config file from the boot folder, I found the option below:

```
# Texas Instruments WL128x FM driver (ST based)
#
CONFIG_RADIO_WL128X=m
```

Does this mean that WL128X is enabled so that I can use that module directly without any kernel reconfiguration ?

I am using a module from TI with model number, WL1835MODCOM8B. But the documentation of this model says that WLAN and Bluetooth, BLE cores are software and hardware compatible with prior WL127x, WL128x and CC256x offerings, facilitating an easy migration to device.

So, if the above entry for WL128x means the device is enabled, then i can use the WL1835 module directly as it is compatible with WL128x as per documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The option you're seeing is building a driver required to use the FM radio component which is part of TI chip combo (these are chips which were targeted for smartphones initially and, therefore, had an FM radio functionality as well).  This is completely unrelated to WiFi.

The WLAN driver to use with these chips is wl18xx (located in `drivers/net/wireless/ti/`). You'll need to configure `CONFIG_WL18XX` and recompile the kernel.

On top of that you'll have to follow Alexandre advice about editing the board file or device tree.

Comment: Thank you.  As I had told you before that in my kernel config file, the following is there CONFIG_WL18XX=m. So, in my system, when I go into the folder, /usr/src/kernels/3.12.0-xillinux-1.3/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wl18xx , I find a bunch of header files and an incomplete makefile. So, I have to just make changes to run make ? This will ensure that the firmware for the wl18xx module is installed ? And I dont need to recompile the kernel or anything ? But, I still need to make changes to device tree so that this module is using the right pins on the hardware

Comment: Currently when I run the make command, the output is make: *** No targets. Stop.
Which is beacuse the makefile is incomplete. The makefile looks like:
 
wl18xx-objs = main.o acx.o tx.o io.o debugfs.o scan.o cmd.o event.o
obj-$(CONFIG_WL18XX) += wl18xx.o

Comment: The Makefile in the driver directory is not incomplete. It's just not built to run as a standalone makefile. It's included by the kernel build makefiles. So you're supposed to run make from the root directory of the kernel. Read up on how to build a kernel module

Answer (score 0):

The WL1835 is using SDIO and UART. Those buses don't have any discovering mechanism for their devices. So, you have to describe how you connected the module to your development board by editing either the board file or the device tree, depending on your platform and kernel version.